# What is the safest practical way to deal with non-required MS Access text fields in queries?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, isnull, oledbdatareader

In querying MS Access, I've learned ([How can I preempt a "Specified cast is not valid" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554087/how-can-i-preempt-a-specified-cast-is-not-valid-exception)) that I have to query defensively where Text (string) values may be empty (or, apparently, in actuality null) by using the "*IIF(ISNULL(colName),'',colName)*" construct, such as:

```
SELECT id, pack_size, IIF(ISNULL(description),'',description), department, subdepartment, IIF(ISNULL(vendor_id),'',vendor_id), IIF(ISNULL(vendor_item),'',vendor_item), avg_cost, list_cost FROM PhunkyPlatypi ORDER BY id
```

I assume that this is only necessary for Text columns that have been designated required == false. Is my ASSumption wrong - do I have to do this with all non-required columns?

Specifically, if I need to query defensively regarding columns of data type double, is this the way to do that:

```
IIF(ISNULL(two_bagger),0.0,two_bagger)
```

?

Or better yet (one can always hope): Is there some cleaner/less obtrusive way of dealing with result sets that do not contain data in every column?

If it makes any difference, I'm querying the MS Access database from a .NET 4.5.1 Web API app using OleDbDataReader (old whine in new wineskins?)

### UPDATE

Re: HansUp's (Reach for the Sky?) suggestion: "*Maybe it would be more productive to attack this from the .Net side and make the code more accommodating of Nulls*", would something like this be the way to do it, or is there a more efficient/safer way:

```
if (null == oleDbD8aReader.GetString(2))
{
    description = "Blank description";
}
else
{
    description = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(2);
}
```

?

### UPDATE 2

I changed the code to check for DBNull, setting the value to a generic one based on the data type (string.empty for Text, 0 for ints, 0.00 for double) when it IS DBNull, but I still get the same err msg.

### UPDATE 3

I'm getting "Specified cast is invalid" on this line:

```
long RedemItemId = (oleDbD8aReader["dbp_id"] is DBNull ? 0 : (long)oleDbD8aReader["dbp_id"]);
```

dbp_id is a LongInt in the Access table

The data being returned from the query includes these values in that column:

```
5
20
30
40
45
60
70
75
90
120
120
```

...so how could any of these values be failling a cast to long? Should I be using "Convert.ToX()" instead of "(long)"? Or...???

Comment: re: your UPDATE 2 - I have updated my answer.

Comment: Actually yes, `Convert.ToX()` would be a better choice. Good suggestion.

Comment: `int iResult = (rdr["numCol"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(rdr["numCol"]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(in response to the add-on question about handling things on the client side...)*

`OleDbDataReader` will return an Access database `Text` field as either `System.String` (if it contains a value), or `System.DBNull` (if it is `Null` in the database).

So, if you want to convert `DBNull` values to empty (zero-length) strings just use

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT txtCol FROM Clients WHERE ID = 3";
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();
string result = rdr["txtCol"].toString();
```

In the cases where you *do* care if the value returned was `DBNull` then test for it

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT txtCol FROM Clients WHERE ID = 3";
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();
string result;
if (rdr["txtCol"] is DBNull)
{
    result = "{That field was Null.}";
}
else
{
    result = rdr["txtCol"].ToString();
}
```

(Note that in C#, `null` and `DBNull` are [different critters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4958379/2144390).)

### Edit

Similarly, for numeric database fields (for example, of type `Double`), you can "force" nulls to zero with

```csharp
cmd.CommandText =
    "SELECT dblCol FROM Clients WHERE ID = 3";
OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();
double dResult = (rdr["dblCol"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(rdr["dblCol"]));
```

Comment: What about for non-Text/String columns? Is DBNull the thing to test for? I reckon so...

Answer (score 2):

*"for Text columns that have been designated required == false ... do I have to do this with all non-required columns?"*

Perhaps.  Columns with other data types (numeric, Date/Time, etc.) could contain Null if you haven't set Required = True for them.  Also, with a `LEFT` or `RIGHT JOIN` you could get Nulls in the unmatched rows even if all columns in the source tables have Required = True.  If you don't want any Nulls in your query output, you would have to do the substitutions for all possible cases.

*"regarding columns of data type double, is this the way to do that"*

```
IIF(ISNULL(two_bagger),0.0,two_bagger)
```

Yes, that should work.  Or you could do it this way if you prefer ...

```
IIF(two_bagger Is Null,0.0,two_bagger)
```

From OleDb, I don't believe there is *"some cleaner/less obtrusive way of dealing with result sets that do not contain data in every column"*.  Maybe it would be more productive to attack this from the `.Net` side and make the code more accommodating of Nulls ... then you wouldn't need to ask the db engine to substitute something else for Nulls.

Answer (score 0):

There is a non SQL non Jet but Access function NZ which could help

```
IIF(ISNULL(description),'',description)
```

almost equal to

```
nz(description,'')
```

Check if it is avaiable through oleDbReader

Comment: Unfortunately, no, `Nz()` is only available in queries that are run from within the Access application itself.